# Retrieve Overwritten View SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Problem: I have accidentally overwrite a view in SnowFlake using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW.
Question: Is there anyway to retrieve the old view i.e. the SQL code?

Comment: A good way to prevent these issues would be to use a version controlled tool to create your tables & views, such as [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/). That way, no matter what happens to your Database, you always have your definitions/DDL stored elsewhere (typically in git/GitHub).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) to find the previous DDL used to create the query.

You can filter results using **QUERY_TYPE** which will help to you to find quickly the right query type.

Comment: This feature is much more flexible than the built-in History UI. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find it in the query history tab using QUERY_TYPE > CREATE, you can search for it over the previous 365 days in the query history. This previous post has the SQL to run:

[View DDL history of CREATE VIEW statement in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742381/view-ddl-history-of-create-view-statement-in-snowflake/61742902#61742902)

Note that this is a big query if your account has run lots of queries over the last year. You can modify it to reduce the scan if necessary if you know more information, such as the month of creation.

If you want a totally informal and lightweight way to version your objects, I wrote one for my internal use that I decided to share. It's a table and stored procedure. Call the stored procedure with the object type and three-part name, and it adds a version row to the table. If it finds a pervious version, it marks the old one obsolete as of the current_timestamp and increments the number of the new version by 1.

https://github.com/GregPavlik/SimpleVersioning/blob/main/install.sql

Comment: Another good way to store historical DDL is to use a version controlled tool, such as [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/), so that you always have your definitions/DDL stored elsewhere (typically in git/GitHub). I'd say it's a bit more of an industry standard, compared to using a custom stored procedure.